# Sql Full Text keyword search - contains or not contains

Tags: sql, join, full-text-search

Hi i was asked to upgrade our website s keyword search section. It needs to be like in the picture.
[image]

The user can select from two different options from select box and it refers to my full text indexed column. Then he/she enter a pharese or word and says add. It goes to "contains box" and it means that search result needs to contains that word. If the user drags it to the other box search results shouldnt contains that word/s. 
I did it some way. But im concerned about the performance. These searches occurs in every 15 seconds in average and the table has ~30 million records.
This is what i did:

```
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (FullTextDB,column1,'"software developer*"') ka on a.refnumber = ka.[key] 
left JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (FullTextDB,column1,'"mvc*" ') ri on a.refnumber = ri.[key]
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (FullTextDB,column2,'"php*" ') yer on a.refnumber = yer.[key] 

WHERE  ri.[key] is null
```

It brings correct results but how can i improve this. I used left join to exclude. Any ideas? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping your search keywords will provide improved performance

example

```
"(A OR B) AND NOT (C)"
```